# JSON Unmarshall not working as expected with structs

Tags: json, go

I have the following code:

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"

type SuperNum struct {
    num string
}

func main() {
    byt := []byte(`{"num":"6.13"}`)

    var dat SuperNum

    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", dat) // I expect this to have a `num` attribute
}
```

Output:

```
{num:}
Program exited.
```

You can run this code [in the golang playground](http://play.golang.org/p/lU9qNrdB-Y).

Because I'm setting a `num` property in the struct and in the JSON and they're both strings, I would have expected the `dat` struct to have a `num` property, with `'hello'`, but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong? What in my mental model of how this should work is incorrect?

**EDIT**

I tried adding the `json` signature to the struct, but it makes no difference (no idea what that actually does).

```
type SuperNum struct {
    num string `json:"num"`
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`num` is by convention not exported as it is lower case. Change it to `Num` and you are able to inspect the result.

```
type SuperNum struct {
    Num string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change `num` to `Num`. The lowercase properties of the structures are not visible.

<kbd>[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2g4aYZXoqo)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

When unmarhalling JSON structures, the properties that you're mapping on must be public (remember that in Go, public and private visibility of struct and module members is denoted by the member's name being upper or lower camel case.

So, first of all, your struct must be defined like this:

```
type SuperNum struct {
    Num string  // <- note the capital "N"
}
```

With this struct, the JSON marshaller will expect the JSON property to be also named `Num`. In order to configure a different property name (like the lowercased `num` in your example), use the `json` annotation for that struct member:

```
type SuperNum struct {
    Num string `json:"num"`
}
```

Comment: So is there a moment where I would set the property in the `SuperNum` struct to `num`? Why?